# Using with rsync to MS SharePoint

Tags: macos, sharepoint, backup, rsync, onedrive

I've searched large and deep, but nothing is available, as far as I can see.

**TLDR**: How can I use `rsync` with a SharePoint installation? (Or something like `rsync`)

**Long description**

We have a large install base of Macs (~50%), Windows (~40%), and Linux (~10%), so our environment is pretty heterogeneous. Being an experimental job we produce a considerable amount of experimental datasets that we need to share, and more importantly, **backup**.

Right now we use external hard drives to store these files and folders, since our computers cannot hold these amount of data (50GB++, for instance, per dataset). And when we need to share, we "physically" share. We mainly we use `rsync` with some kind of backend (what kind is not important), but this solution requires computers to be left turned on, and act as servers.

For reasons that I will not bother you with, **we cannot leave a computer on** after work.

Having OneDrive for Business seemed a very promising technology to use, since we have more than **1TB per user**. We could start syncing out datasets from our computers and hard drives, and we could share even when computers are turned off.

We are aware that we may hit some drawbacks, as not being able to actually share, having some limits about the number of objects (files/directories), but we will handle them later.

I prefer `rsync`, but right now we're open to any solution.

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive for Business has a download that will allow you to synchronize a directory locally.  https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/

For a Linux platform, you should be able to use onedrive-d found here:
https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d

Comment: As I said in the question, our computers cannot hold the amount of data we need to sync, they're stored on (several) external drives.

Comment: Linux Github repo has changed to https://github.com/xybu/onedrived-dev

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old question, but it's unanswered. Maybe a solution could be https://rclone.org/. Rclone is a command line program to sync files and directories to and from the cloud.